# How to change context menu item's style if command is disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a context menu and at certain point i disable some of the commands bound to context menu items.

**what works:**

when the command gets disabled , clicking on the menu item does not call the execute method on the command as i wanted.

**What does not work:**

Both commands that can exucute and those which cant look identical!! 
my users cant tell the difference.

**Problem:**

How can I change the style to display this change. Change in background color, border color, foreground color , a tooltip... anything will be acceptable..

I experimented with xaml and was unable to solve this.
(I am a noob with xaml so my attempts are not even worth pasting here :) )

**xaml :**

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="100"  Background="Transparent"  ContextMenu="{Binding Path=ContextMenu}" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderColor}">
```

**Binding:**

```
public override ContextMenu ContextMenu
        {
            get
            {
                return new ContextMenu
                           {
                               ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>
                                                 {
                                                     new MenuItem
                                                         {
                                                             Header = IsSharedFieldView? "Delete Shared Field" :"Delete Field" ,
                                                             Command = DeleteFieldCommand 
                                                         }
                                                 }
                           };

            }
        }
```

Comment: you should post you xaml context menu

Comment: @blindmeis pasted the code ( there is hardly any xaml)

Comment: any particular reason why you fill up the contextmenu from a collection in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox >
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Add" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                    </Menu>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Its just demo and you can have idea from this . and you can bind IsEnabled to your VM Command.CanExecute . I hope this will help.

Comment: i tried this but apparently the IsEnabled property is never set and I cant think of any way to access the command to use the canExecute.

Comment: how you are disabling the Command/MenuItem so that command action is not fired

Comment: i call RaiseCanExecuteChanged().. Now clicking on the context menu item does not fire the command. so i am assuming that the RaiseCanExecuteChanged()  worked   and disabled the command. but the isEnabled is not set to false :s

Comment: Bind IsEnabled to YourVMCommand.CanExecute , YourVMCommand is your VM command to which your corresponding MenuItem Command is binded. or try IsReadonly instead of IsEnabled above.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here, is that ContextMenu actually inherits from ItemsControl, this works on my machine:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();

            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ICommand>>();
            MenuItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ICommand>("One", OneCommand));
            MenuItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, ICommand>("Two", null));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<String, ICommand>> MenuItems { get; set; }

        #region OneCommand
        DelegateCommand _OneCommand;
        public DelegateCommand OneCommand
        {
            get { return _OneCommand ?? (_OneCommand = new DelegateCommand(One, CanOne)); }
        }

        public bool CanOne()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void One()
        {

        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicContextMenuTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Path Data="M 10,2 L 17.5,2 L 17.5,0 L 23,4.5 L 17.5,9 L 17.5,7.3 L 10,7.3 L 10,2" Fill="Green">
            <Path.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Key">
                    <ContextMenu.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Value}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.Resources>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Path.ContextMenu>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice a few things:

- You no longer bind to a ContextMenu (viewmodels shouldn't be aware of controls), instead you bind to a collection of `string`(Header)/`ICommand`(Command)
- When an item's command's `CanExecute` returns false, the bound control's `IsEnabled` property becomes false. You can have a trigger on that property to modify the appearance of the bound control.

Comment: I tried that but for some reason when CanExecute returns false, it does not update the IsEnabled propery.. :s probably a mistake i made somewhere..  and since I am out of time I decided to put a popup error message if command invoked at wrong time.  any ways thaks for your answer

Comment: you need to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() on the DelegateCommand when it should be re-evaluated

Comment: I called that. The command gets disabled. (Clicking on the context menu does not cause the execute method to be called)

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked :

Initially i was binding a ContextMenu from my view model and the isEnabled was not working.

Instead of that I created the context menu in xaml and bound the itemsSource from the viewModel.

Now the menu item gets disabled and the triggers are working.

Not sure what i was doing wrong but this fixed it :)